# Multiple Mongoose Queries before rendering view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've a form with multiple dropdown lists that needs to be populated with values from MongoDB database, in my route file code seems something like this:

```
Make.find({},function(err,allMakes){
       if(err){
           console.log("error while trying to get all makes from the database");
       }else{
           makes = allMakes;
}

Color.find({},function(err,allColors){
       if(err){
           console.log("error while trying to get all colors from the database");
       }else{
           colors = allColors;
}
```

I've 8 occurrences where i need to query the DB then put the result in local variable in order to pass it to render function as a param like this:

```
res.render("viewname",{makes:makes,colors:colors....etc});
```

the problem is that in my view file i get undefined for the params.

any solutions for the asynch nodejs code?!

Comment: Can you please tell me what the actual problem is, what are you looking for?

Comment: @GandalftheWhite the problem was the values to be sent as params to render method don't get assigned with the expected value, in order words, the render method is getting executed before the methods calls to initiate the params.

Answer (score 3):

The MongoDB calls are asynchronous, meaning the values of makes, colors, etc. are not being set before res.render("viewname"); is being called. You need to nest your async calls, use Promise.all, or ideally use a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to run your DB calls in parallel, and then call res.render only after all of the DB callbacks have set the values that should be passed to the view.

For example, if you're nesting your calls:

```
Make.find({}, function(err,allMakes) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error while trying to get all makes from the database");
    } else {
        makes = allMakes;
    }

    Color.find({}, function(err,allColors) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error while trying to get all colors from the database");
        } else {
            colors = allColors;
        }

        res.render("viewname",{makes:makes,colors:colors....etc}); 
    }
}
```

Comment: And maybe add in a little error handling since makes and colors won't be defined if err comes up true.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the two functions are in the same (parent) function. You cannot call two methods like that and expect to have results at the same time when you will need them. You can imbricate methods like:

```
Make.find({},function(err,allMakes){
   if(err){
       console.log("error while trying to get all makes from the database");
   }else{
       makes = allMakes;

   Color.find({},function(err,allColors){
       if(err){
           console.log("error while trying to get all colors from the database");
       }else{
           colors = allColors;
           methodForRender(makes, colors);
    }
}
```

methodForRender can be a callback function in which you will return Makes and Colors, or just a function. But I prefer a callback because it is better to have such methods in a model file, and render views one in a route file

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody who tried to help in answering this question.

I've found the solution, the solution is using nodejs module called async

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.series

the working code looks like this:

```
router.get("/new",function(req,res){

   // get vehicles makes available in the DB
   var makes;
   var colors;
   var categories;
   var usages;
   var registrationCenters;
   var fuelTypes;
   var insuranceCompanies;
   var insuranceCoverages;

   async.series([function(callback){
       Make.find({},function(err,allMakes){
           if(err) return callback(err);
           makes = allMakes;
           callback(null,allMakes);
       })
   },function(callback){
       Color.find({},function(err,allColors){
           if(err) return callback(err);
           colors = allColors;
           callback(null,allColors);
       })
   },function(callback){
      Category.find({},function(err,allCates){
          if(err) return callback(err);
          categories = allCates;
          callback(null,allCates);
      }) 
   },function(callback){
       Usage.find({},function(err,allUsages){
           if(err) return callback(err);
           usages = allUsages;
           callback(null,allUsages);
       })
   },function(callback){
       RegistraionCenter.find({},function(err,allCenters){
           if(err) return callback(err);
           registrationCenters = allCenters;
           console.log(allCenters);
           callback(null,allCenters);
       })
   },function(callback){
        FuelType.find({},function(err,allTypes){
            if(err) return callback(err);
            fuelTypes = allTypes;

            callback(null,allTypes);
        })  
   },
   function(callback){
       InsuranceCompanies.find({},function(err,allCompanies){
           if(err) return callback(err);
           insuranceCompanies = allCompanies;
           callback(null,allCompanies);
       })
   },function(callback){
       InsuranceCoverages.find({},function(err,allCoverages){
           if(err) return callback(err);

           insuranceCoverages = allCoverages;
           callback(null,allCoverages);
       })
   }
   ],function(err){
       res.render("vehicles/new",{makes:makes,colors:colors,categories:categories,usages:usages,
           registrationCenters:registrationCenters,fueltypes:fuelTypes,InsuranceCompanies:insuranceCompanies,insuranceCoverages:insuranceCoverages}
       );
   });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, res.render() was executing before the queries finished hence crashing the app.
You can solve it by something like this:

```
router.get('/yourroute', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allMakes = await Make.find({});
    const allColors = await Color.find({});
    res.render('viewname', { allMakes, allColors });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```